# Javascript help | Jquery plugin socialist

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have and it is not working when I click the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->

<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

    <title>The Conceited Cat | a Modest Mouse fansite</title>
    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/jquery.socialist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.socialist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {   
                $('nav a').click(function() {
                    var social = $(this).attr('title');
                    var artist = $(this).attr('rel');
                    return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>THE CONCEITED CAT</h1>

        <h3>a Modest Mouse fansite</h3>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href=
                    "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIJdJU2RCaOieKNh7vCxWCA"
                    rel="UCIJdJU2RCaOieKNh7vCxWCA" title="youtube">modest
                    mouse</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="socialistContainer"></div><script type="text/javascript">

        $("#socialistContainer").socialist({ 
        networks: [ 
        { name: social , id: artist } 
        ]
        });


        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it works great if i manually put in name: 'youtube' , id:'UCIJdJU2RCaOieKNh7vCxWCA' 
but need it to work with the link.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
clay

Answer (score 0):

`social` and `artist` aren't defined until the `<a>` element is clicked, and even then (since you used `var`) they are scoped to that function.

When you try to pass them to `socialist` they are both out of scope and not yet defined.

The solution is probably to move the call to `socialist` so it is *inside* the function you use as the click handler.

Comment: i moved $("#socialistContainer").socialist({ 
        networks: [ 
        { name: social , id: artist } 
        ]
        }); inside the click function and still not working, is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you clicking on the link?

Comment: is this what you mean?$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav a').click(function() {
        var social = $(this).attr('title');
        var artist = $(this).attr('rel');
        return false;
        $("#socialistContainer").socialist({
            networks: [{
                name: social,
                id: artist
            }]
        });
    });
});

Comment: `return false` will end the function! Put everything you want to do *before* the `return` statement.

Comment: gotcha, thanks.. I also had to add function(e), e.prevent default to prevent the link from trying to connect then stopping all others.